# Redirect/rewrite alternative domains to root domain with apache2/htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, dns

I 2 domains with and without the www prefix. When a user visits any of these domains, I want it to automatically reroute to a chosen 1 of them.

For example:

```
domain.com
www.domain.com
domain.co.uk
www.domain.co.uk
```

When a user visits `www.domain.com`, `domain.co.uk` or `www.domain.co.uk`, it will rewrite to `domain.com`

So far, I have my apache2 virtual host block setup like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3060/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3060/
  ServerName domain.com
  ServerAlias www.domain.com
  ServerAlias domain.co.uk
  ServerAlias www.domain.co.uk
</VirtualHost>
```

But this doesn't do the rewriting/rerouting. I need to also make sure that it takes into account any paths. For example, `www.domain.co.uk/test` would change to `domain.com/test`

Any ideas how I can do this in the virtual host block? I'm assuming I would split the 3 domains to be rewritten into a separate block and treat them there, but really not sure how to accomplish all the rules I need.

Comment: Not sure I'm following. When you access either of the aliases, it serves the content of `ServerName`. Are you actually looking to *redirect* the aliases to the main domain?

Comment: @MikeRockett Yes, at the moment, if I visit domain.co.uk it servers the content, but the browser address bar shows domain.co.uk. I need it to show domain.com for the user and for search engines to only use that domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your comment, you want to redirect the three aliases to the main domain, and you've stated that you would like to do this within the virtual host configuration.

```bash
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...

    RewriteEngine on

    # If using one of the aliases ...
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.co\.uk

    # ... redirect to the main domain
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=302,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

You can also add the `Rewrite*` directives in your domain's `.htaccess` file.

To make the redirect permanent, change 302 to 301 - this basically instructs browsers and search engines to cache the redirect.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this now.

Comment: Works exactly as I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Out of interest, if I only wanted to redirect the www version of the root domain, do I remove the second `RewriteCond` in your example and the `[OR]` at the end of the first `RewriteCond`?